# PL/SQL I want the corresponding column of MAX(O.CO_YEAR). How to do it?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Below is the code for PL/SQL query for which I have to grab the names of the instructors who are qualified to teach a particular course when name is supplied along with number of times they have taught this course and the last time (year and term) when they taught this course.

I have done most part of the question, but couldn't figure out how to get the corresponding details of the max(o.co_year)   i.e. term

```
declare
gname varchar2(20);
count_id number(2);
id varchar(20);
year1 number(4);

cursor abc   // cursor 1
     is
        SELECT  i.i_gname
          into gname
        FROM INSTRUCTOR I 
        WHERE i.i_id in (
        SELECT t.i_id  FROM TeachingQualification T
        WHERE t.c_id in (SELECT c.c_id  FROM  COURSE C
        WHERE c.c_title = 'Advanced Database App')) ;


cursor bcd // cursor two
    is
        select o.i_id, count(o.i_id), max(o.co_year)
          into id, count_id, year1
        from courseoffering o
        where (o.i_id = i_id and o.c_id = 1234567)
        group by o.i_id;


Begin
open abc;
open bcd; 

loop

FETCH abc into gname;
exit when abc%NOTFOUND;

FETCH bcd into id, count_id, year1;
exit when bcd%NOTFOUND;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('NAME: ' || gname || '  Number of times taught ' || count_id || ' Year ' || year1 || );  // want to output corresponding column details for the year1 attribute.

end loop;
close bcd;
close abc;
end;
```

PL/SQL I want the corresponding column of MAX(O.CO_YEAR). How to do it?

Comment: Why are you doing all of this in PL/SQL? You could write this all as a single SQL statement.

Comment: Yeah I know, but its an university task which I'm suppose to be implemented in PL/SQL.

Comment: what do you mean by "want to output corresponding column details for the year1 attribute." ?

Comment: I meant I have 5 columns in COURSEOFFERING table i.e. A, B, C, D, E, F........when we do MAX of COLUMN D I want to output MAX value plus corresponding value in COLUMN B

Comment: Look into using analytic functions. These are like aggregates but can be returned for each row. See http://psoug.org/reference/analytic_functions.html for example.

Answer (score 2):

> Yeah I know, but its an university task which I'm suppose to be implemented in PL/SQL.

Blah! I'd rather that your university teaches you about the proper use of PLSQL and SQL, and gave a meaningful task. If you can do something in SQL, then do it in SQL.
Also: Why are your cursors containing the `INTO` keyword? Why do you need a loop? It seems you only ever expect 1 returned value?

I dissected your code a bit:

```
--instructors who are qualified to teach a course
SELECT i.i_gname --instructor name
  FROM INSTRUCTOR I 
 WHERE i.i_id IN ( SELECT t.i_id --instructor_id
                     FROM TeachingQualification T
                    WHERE t.c_id in (SELECT c.c_id --course_id
                                       FROM  COURSE C
                                      WHERE c.c_title = 'Advanced Database App'));


--instructors who taught a course, with amount and last time
SELECT o.i_id instructor_id, count(o.i_id) times_taught, max(o.co_year) last_time_taught
  FROM courseoffering o
 WHERE o.c_id = 1234567 --course_id
 GROUP BY o.i_id;

--all instructors (ID) who taught advanced database app, how many times, and last time
--consider that this may produce NO_DATA_FOUND
SELECT o.i_id instructor_id, count(o.i_id) times_taught, max(o.co_year) last_time_taught
  FROM course c
  JOIN courseoffering o 
    ON c.c_id = o.c_id
 WHERE c.c_title = 'Advanced Database App'
 GROUP BY o.i_id; 

-- i don't think teachingqualification is required. The last select providers instructor IDs.
-- There is no need to go through that table, unless it would contain extra data you'd want to
-- filter by. Since courseoffering is being queried, and it has instructors, it stands to reason
-- that those instructor are qualified to teach the course.
SELECT  (SELECT i_gname FROM instructor WHERE i_id = o.i_id) instructor
       ,count(o.i_id) times_taught
       , max(o.co_year) last_time_taught
  FROM course c
  JOIN courseoffering o 
    ON c.c_id = o.c_id
 WHERE c.c_title = 'Advanced Database App'
 GROUP BY o.i_id;

-- Look, if you do want a PLSQL block for this, go ahead.
BEGIN
   FOR r IN (SELECT  (SELECT i_gname FROM instructor WHERE i_id = o.i_id) instructor
                    ,count(o.i_id) times_taught
                    , max(o.co_year) last_time_taught
               FROM course c
               JOIN courseoffering o 
                 ON c.c_id = o.c_id
              WHERE c.c_title = 'Advanced Database App'
              GROUP BY o.i_id)
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('NAME: ' || r.instructor || '  Number of times taught ' || r.times_taught || ' Year ' || r.last_time_taught);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Oh, and please give your columns meaningful names. Call it `instructor_id` instead of `i_id` for example.

I set up some example data:

```
create table course (id number(5,0), cname varchar2(50), constraint course_pk primary key (id))
/
create table courseoffering(id number(5,0), course_id number(5,0), instructor_id number(5,0), course_year number(5,0), constraint offering_pk primary key (id), constraint course_fk foreign key (course_id) references course (id))
/
insert into course values (1, 'Tech I');
insert into course values (2, 'Basic SQL');
insert into course values (3, 'Advanced SQL');
--Instructor 1
insert into courseoffering values (1, 1, 1, 2009); --Tech I
insert into courseoffering values (2, 1, 1, 2010); --Tech I
insert into courseoffering values (3, 1, 1, 2011); --Tech I
insert into courseoffering values (4, 2, 1, 2011); --Basic SQL
insert into courseoffering values (5, 2, 1, 2012); --Basic SQL
--Instructor 2
insert into courseoffering values (6, 2, 2, 2008); --Basic SQL
insert into courseoffering values (7, 2, 2, 2009); --Basic SQL
insert into courseoffering values (8, 2, 2, 2010); --Basic SQL
insert into courseoffering values (9, 3, 2, 2010); --Advanced SQL
insert into courseoffering values (10, 3, 2, 2011); --Advanced SQL
insert into courseoffering values (11, 3, 2, 2012); --Advanced SQL
insert into courseoffering values (12, 1, 2, 2009); --Tech I
insert into courseoffering values (13, 1, 2, 2010); --Tech I
commit;
```

Running this:

```
SELECT c.cname, o.instructor_id, count(o.instructor_id) times_taught, max(o.course_year) last_time_taught
  FROM course c
  JOIN courseoffering o 
    ON c.id = o.course_id
 GROUP BY c.cname, o.instructor_id
 ORDER BY c.cname, o.instructor_id;
```

Produces:

```
CNAME          INSTRUCTOR_ID  TIMES_TAUGHT   LAST_TIME_TAUGHT
Advanced SQL   2              3              2012
Basic SQL      1              2              2012
Basic SQL      2              3              2010
Tech I         1              3              2011
Tech I         2              2              2010
```

You can even easily turn the required data into a view.
No PLSQL required. Only a couple of lines in SQL. And if you want it in PLSQL you can still use a loop to cover multiple instructors per course, or if you narrow it to one course and one instructor, some variables. Always minimize switching between SQL and PLSQL contexts.

Comment: Amen! Sorry, but here it had to be said.

Comment: Thank you so much TOM, It is kind of eye opener for me. The way you structured query and the explanation will be very useful to me. Thanks once again!!!

Answer (score 0):

Cursors in Oracle can have parameters. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm#BABHICAF for details.

How it *might* work in your code:

```
cursor bcd(p_c_id courseoffering.c_id%type) // cursor two
is
    select o.i_id, count(o.i_id), max(o.co_year)
      into id, count_id, year1
    from courseoffering o
    where (o.i_id = i_id and o.c_id = p_c_id)
    group by o.i_id;
```

Comment: Code runs, but with no output after implementing changes you mentioned above.

Comment: For a start: `o.i_id = i_id` is always true and can be removed, but that won't magically make *your* code work.